# Check if ManyToMany relationship on certain date exists, then exclude that entry

Tags: python, django

I have this model:

```
class Assignment(models.Model)
    assignment_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    chosen_driver = models.ManyToManyField('driver.Driver', blank=True, verbose_name=_(
        "Chosen driver"), related_name="driver_chosen")
    ...
```

A chosen driver can only have one assignment per day. So when getting the `Assignment` queryset I want to check for the `assignment_date` and then see if the `Driver` model already has an assignment with this date.

So I though something like this:

```
driver = get_object_or_404(Driver, pk=1)

dcl = []
for entry in driver.driver_chosen.all():
    dcl.append(entry.assignment_date)
```

Then we have a list with all the dates of assignments where this `Driver` is chosen.

Then when constructing the queryset of `Assignment` maybe something like this to compare the dates to each other and exclude from the queryset:

```
for entry in Assignment.objects.all()
    if entry.assignment_date in dcl:
        queryset = Assignment.objects.exclude(entry.pk)
        return queryset
```

But this returns a `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object` error.

Can someone help?

Comment: Is the code you posted correct? Your model has a m2m field called ```chosen_driver``` but your query says ```driver.driver_chosen.all()```

Comment: It's the `related_name`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

Comment: My mistake, overlooked that. The error you are getting is this line ```queryset = Assignment.objects.exclude(entry.pk)``` - the syntax for ```.exclude``` is ```exclude(field_name=value)```, e.g. ```queryset = Assignment.objects.exclude(pk=entry.pk)```

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. Your second iteration will return as soon as the first date is found. Is this what you want? Or do you want a queryset of Assignment to which a driver can be assigned?

Comment: Yes exactly! I want a queryset to which a driver can still be assigned because he still is available on that date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a queryset with all `Assignments` to which a driver can be assigned I would suggest avoiding playing around with `lists` but doing it all in a query. E.g.:

```
driver = get_object_or_404(Driver, pk=1)
dates = Assignment.objects.filter(chosen_driver=driver).values_list('assignment_date', flat=True)
qs = Assignment.objects.exclude(assignment_date__in=dates)
```

or in one line:

```
qs = Assignment.objects.exclude(
       assignment_date__in=Assignment.objects.filter(
        chosen_driver=driver
     ).values_list('assignment_date', flat=True)
)
```